# android calendar event issues with android 2.3

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am presenting user with the add calendar event screen with the below mentioned code.

For example the following will prompt the user if an event should be created with certain details.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
intent.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
startActivity(intent);
```

This part is working fine with Android 4.0 and above but not working on android 2.3....?
I want this to work on all android OS between 2.3 till 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this also if you it to do with some other way :

```
mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, COLS, null, null, null);
```

its a contentProvider for calender .

Comment: you can also refer this link also :        http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCalendar/article.html

Comment: Ok..can you please make me understand what is this code trying to do?how can i integrate with my code?